# 70s Sci-fi story. Drink-driving motorist sent to be re-educated. Made to drive fast as punishment

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, young-adult

What I remember is it's about a teen who has committed crime like drunk driving and is set to some sort of re-education center, meets a girl, has to drive fast a lot.

It was dystopian in nature and turned out that the kids were in a kind of an experiment in mind-control or conditioning due to their juvenile deliquency tendencies. I think the main character would drive at super high speeds on a track but then get shocked or some such.

Comment: What science fiction or fantasy elements were there in this novel? If it's not SF/F, then I'm afraid it's off-topic for this site.

Comment: It was dystopian in nature and turned out that the kids were in a kind of an experiment in mind-control or conditioning due to their juvenile deliquency tendencies.  I think the main character would drive at super high speeds on a track but then get shocked or some such.

Answer (score 7):

The story "The Speeders" by Arthur Tofte has several matching elements to your story.  From [Bev Hankins at goodreads](http://www.goodreads.com/review/show/165639158):

> "The Speeders" by Arthur Tofte: In the world of the future, the government has supposedly ensured that vehicles will be safe--no speeding and no accidents. But there are always the young joyriders who will find their way around the laws and restrictions. These young men find that when they joyride and manage to break the speeding laws one too many times that they are incarcerated--not in prison, but in Traverse Park. In what seems like a speed-demon's paradise, all bets are off. The speeders can go as fast as they want and drive as recklessly as they want. Is it really the freedom from restrictions that it appears? Or is there a more chilling motive behind the speeder's park?

Comment: While matching up on the speeding, there was no electro-shock involved, no actual attempt at reform. Instead, they basically left the kids there to kill each other. Good story, though.

Comment: That's got to be it!  I will go look it up!  Thank you so much.  Has troubled me for so long!